# Ubuntu 14.04 boot hangs at logo after updating

Tags: boot, upstart

Yesterday, I did a `update`/`dist-upgrade`. Today, I powered on the machine and it was hanging at the loading screen with logo and cycling dots - I've waited at this screen for about an hour several times with no results. If I interrupt `upstart` with ctrl-alt-del, bootup resumes/completes, but it puts me at tty console login. `X` does start, a few seconds later, but a dialog about graphics being configured incorrectly is immediately brought up. **Update**: The X issue was resolved by doing `apt-get install nvidia-current`. Interrupt issue still stands.

Unfortunately, every lead I've found as to why this might be happening has turned into a dead end. [Here's my `boot.log`](http://pastebin.com/Vbh5pLKe) (from `/var/log`) showing where I interrupted the startup. You can see it hangs just as it starts "enable remaining boot-time encrypted block devices" (this is from `cryptdisks`), but removing that service makes no difference. I've tried pretty much everything from [this Mint bug report](https://www.google.com/search?client=ubuntu&channel=fs&q=enable%20remaining%20boot-time%20encrypted&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8), which describes symptoms nearly identical to mine, to no avail. At this point, I'm fairly sure that `cryptdisks` is a red herring, and that it's something else entirely.

I've also found that resuming startup from recovery mode seems to load things in a different order. `Upstart` still hangs, but not after `cryptdisks`. If I ctrl-alt-del, it brings me to the graphical login manager instead of a tty, and I can login successfully. However, the system still isn't fully functional; USB plug and play seems not to work, I can't use my second monitor, and I have to manually do `start resolvconf` to access the internet. [Here's the boot.log from one of those startups.](http://pastebin.com/uJNVQczf)

I should add that I am encrypting my HDD with `LUKS`, and the hang happens after I successfully enter the decryption password. Here's my `fstab`, in case it has anything to do with things:

```
# /etc/fstab: static file system information.
#
# Use 'blkid' to print the universally unique identifier for a
# device; this may be used with UUID= as a more robust way to name devices
# that works even if disks are added and removed. See fstab(5).
#
# <file system> <mount point>   <type>  <options>       <dump>  <pass>
/dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-root /               ext4    errors=remount-ro 0       1
# /boot was on /dev/sda1 during installation
UUID=9e7c1e90-f3e4-4075-b3b0-e3ccb6d933c7 /boot           ext2    defaults        0       2
/dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-swap_1 none            swap    sw              0       0
```

What's going on here?

Comment: are you using nvidia or some type of proprietary graphics? if so, you need to reinstall the driver after upgrading your kernel. to avoid this, you can have dkms installed when you install the driver so you don't have to reinstall it every time you upgrade the kernel. Also, aside from that, you should be able to boot an older kernel by choosing more options or advanced options or something like that from the grub screen. From there, choose one of the older kernel versions.

Comment: this might help http://askubuntu.com/questions/141606/how-to-fix-the-system-is-running-in-low-graphics-mode-error

Comment: Forgot to put in OP - I did try reverting back to the kernel I was using yesterday, and it didn't seem to help. I don't have any nvidia-specific package, or fglrx installed. I feel like the low graphics mode is a symptom, not a cause, but I'll try to investigate further if maybe I do have something proprietary.

Comment: Running `lspci` revealed that I am (and was) using a NVIDIA card, but did not have the drivers installed. Doing `apt-get install nvidia-current` allowed me to get to the graphical login after a normal boot, but I stil have to interrupt `upstart` with a ctrl-alt-del, and I still have to manually start the `resolvconf` service to access the internet. Maybe they are unrelated problems.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**The root cause was a huge number of files in my `/tmp` directory.**

I'd used the `/tmp` directory to store millions of files earlier. It turns out that having that many files there causes the service which cleans `/tmp` to take a long, long time (duh). After moving the files out of `/tmp`, the problem is solved. It had nothing to do with the upgrade; that was just a coincidence.

---

In case it helps anyone later, here's the process I used to figure it out. I enabled the ["Magic SysRq key"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic_SysRq_key) by changing `etc/sysctl.d/10-magic-sysrq.conf`. Then, I reproduced the problem by rebooting; when startup hung, I hit <kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>SysRq</kbd>-<kbd>t</kbd>. This dumped the following in the kernel buffer, read using `dmesg`:

```
[   36.318527] SysRq : Show Blocked State
[   36.318696]   task                        PC stack   pid father
[   36.318719] find            D ffff88041dd93480     0   839    788 0x00000000
[   36.318721]  ffff880405d07a48 0000000000000082 ffff880401136000 ffff880405d07fd8
[   36.318723]  0000000000013480 0000000000013480 ffff880401136000 ffff88041dd93d18
[   36.318725]  ffff88041dfab460 0000000000000002 ffffffff811ef380 ffff880405d07ac0
```

It dumps a lot more than this, but this is the relevant part. This shows the blocked task is `find`. After that, it was just a matter of a knowledgeable friend knowing that the `/tmp` cleaning service was a likely culprit.

Answer (score 4):

Thank-you, Chaosed0, for coming back with your solution (i.e. huge number of files in /tmp).  [I tried to post this as a comment but I don't have enough reputation points]

I ran into the same issue with Ubuntu server (14.04) and it was very difficult to diagnose until I found your post.

When I rebooted the machine, it would appear to get blocked right before it would normally show the login console.  It could be unblocked by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Del</kbd>, which would cause a log message to be printed that `wait-for-state (rcplymouth-shutdown)` had been terminated.  That log message sent me down the wrong path of poking various plymouth scripts and then trying to disable plymouth completely :-(

In actual fact, the boot process wasn't deadlocked, it was just waiting for the clean-up of `/tmp` to complete.  That machine had tens of thousands of files under `/tmp`, so it was taking a long long long time to do the clean-up.

**So the fix for me was to boot into recovery, get a root shell and then `rm -rf /tmp/*`.  After an hour or so the `rm` job completed.  Then I rebooted and everything worked normally.**

It would be great if a log message could be printed when the clean-up of `/tmp` starts.